# Using ODE to plot particle-motion with scipy.integrate.solve_ivp

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode, differential-equations

### My Problem:

> A positively charged particle  (mass = 2 * 10<sup>-27</sup> kg) is moving along the x-axis. It is travelling in a homogenous magnetic field such that the field axis in z-direction. The energy of the particle is 2 MeV and B = 4 T. Use a ODE solver to plot the motion of the particle for 1 microseconds.

### My attempt of solving the problem

##### Note that I have used question marks where I am unsure.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

initialZ = [?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?] # = [positionX, positionY, positionZ, velocityX, velocityY, velocityZ]
t0 = 0
tf = 1*(10**-6) # 1 microsecond = 1*10^6 seconds
times = (t0, tf)

def ivf(t, Z):
  x, y, z = Z[0], Z[1], Z[2]
  u, v, w = Z[3], Z[4], Z[5]
  return np.array([u, v, w, ?, ?, ?])

s = solve_ivp(ivf, times, initialZ)
```

### My question

##### `what should the question marks (?) in the code be replaced with?`

I have tried to solve the ODE as an initial value problem. I tried to determine inital velocity by equating the lorentz force and centripetal force. I am very new to differential equations and it is therefore difficult to know If I am doing things in the correct way. (note that the first three values of my initialZ vector represents positions x, y and z, and the last three values represent velocity in the x, y and z direction). I am grateful for any help or guidance.

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: @ShlomiF , I have updated the question now :)

Comment: So you have some particle moving with `y=z=0` and a velocity given by `0.5*m*v^2=2MeV` and then (unphysically) switch on a homogeneous magnetic field without transition. Or in other words, you have a particle in that magnetic field with `x=y=z=0`, `vy=vz=0`, `vx=v`. However, knowledge of the mass of the particle appears to be crucial.

Comment: Lutz , sorry I forgot to add that in the question, the mass should be (m = 2 × 10^-27). Now that we have the mass, should I instead equate the energy with the kinetic energy to get the initial velocity? How do I include the affect the B-field have on the motion of the particle? Should I include the centripetal force in the next step?

Comment: Cross-posted to https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/37705/using-ode-to-plot-particle-motion-with-scipy-integrate-solve-ivp

Comment: Would it then not be better to just say that the particle is a proton, with the mass rounded from 1.67e-27 to 2e-27, where it is then clear that it has charge of +1e?

Answer (score 2):

Let us set up the ode and then the initial conditions. From the magnetic force equations and Newton's second law, **a** = (q B / m) **v** * **z**. I'm using * to represent the cross product and **x**, **y**, and **z** are unit vectors. In your question you didn't give a charge q for the particle, I'm assuming you are doing a proton and just rounded the mass of 1.67 to 2. You will see that we just need 4 equations and 4 initial conditions as this problem is 2D in nature.

We have that **a** = (q B / m) (v_y **x** - v_x **y**). Note there is no **z** term! We need to write these 2 second order odes as four first order odes so ode solver can work it out. We know that **a** = d**v**/dt.

1. dv_x / dt = (q B / m) v_y
2. dv_y / dt = -(q B / m) v_x
3. dx/dt = v_x
4. dy/dt = v_y

The initial condition is that the velocity is v_x0 = Sqrt(2 E / m) where E is 2 MeV, v_y0 = 0, and lets just have the particle start at the origin, so x0 = y0 = 0.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make sure everything is SI
q = 1.602176634E-19 # charge assuming it is a proton
B = 4 # magnetic field magnitude
m = 2E-27 # mass
E =  2 * 1.60218E-13 # kinetic energy in joules
C = q * B / m # constant for convenience
v0x = np.sqrt(2 * E / m)

initialZ = [0, 0, v0x, 0] # = [positionX, positionY, velocityX, velocityY]

def ivf(t, Z) :
# Z[2] is vx, Z[3] is vy
    dxdt = Z[2]
    dydt = Z[3]
    dvxdt = C * Z[3]
    dvydt = -C * Z[2]
    return [dxdt, dydt, dvxdt, dvydt]

sol = solve_ivp(ivf, [0, 1E-6], initialZ, method='Radau') # 1 microsecond = 1*10^6 seconds

plt.plot(sol.y[0], sol.y[1])
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Displacement on point particle')
plt.show()
```

What I am expecting is circular motion like in a cyclotron. Here is a rough graph I made,

[image]

I was able to get it a bit smooth by playing with the integration method. I'm sure you will be able to tinker and play around with different things until you get a satisfactory result.

Comment: One can get more points for a better curvature by setting `atol`, `rtol` and `max_step` to sensible values, or use the "dense output" interpolation to get more points per step.